# Laravel + Mysql: Retrieve POI's within a bounding box

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, geocoding

I have a database table with POI's that i want to connect with a record in my Geo table (containing cities, countries).

- Within the POI table i have a Lat & Lon field.
- Within the Geo table i have 4 coordinates, for West/East and North/South

[image]

I'm using Laravel 5 / Eloquent and Mysql. The coordinates are stored as a decimal (11,8). I can add multiple columns if needed.

How can i check if a POI is located within those 4 coordinates?

Comment: What's exactly POI ?

Comment: POI = Points Of Interest

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, use mysql's built-in spatial data types and functions.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql supports [spatial data types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-datatypes.html) and [functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-analysis-functions.html) that were designed to make such calculations easy.

Define your POIs as POINT and your rectangle as GEOMETRY. Use the [ST_Contains()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html#function_st-contains) function to test whether the point is within the rectangle:

```
select * from yourtable
where st_contains(rectangle_field, point_field)
```

As far as I know, Laravel does not directly support these daya types and functions, so you have to resort to raw sql.